# What does mean "?" after variable in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, operators

What does this condition mean?

```
if (!helper?.Settings.HasConfig ?? false)
```

P.S.

- `helper` is variable of some `class`
- `Settings` is some *field*
- `HasConfig` is *field* too

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Well, `?.` is a **null-conditional** operator

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx

```
x?.y
```

means return `null` if `x` is null and `x.y` otherwise

`??` is a **null-coalescing operator**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

```
x ?? y
```

means if `x == null` return `y`, otherwise `x`

Combining all the above

```
helper?.Settings.HasConfig ?? false
```

means: return `false` if

```
helper == null or
helper.Settings.HasConfig == null
```

otherwise return

```
helper.Settings.HasConfig
```

The code without `??` and `?.` `if` can be rewritten into *cumbersome*

```
if (!(helper == null 
        ? false
        : (helper.Settings.HasConfig == null 
             ? false
             : helper.Settings.HasConfig)))
```

Answer (score 8):

Check the [C# operator list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx):

x?.y – null conditional member access. Returns null if the left hand operand is null.

x ?? y – returns x if it is non-null; otherwise, returns y.

So `helper?.Settings` will return null if `helper` is null otherwise it will return `helper.Settings`

if `helper.Settings` is not null and `helper.Settings.HasConfig` is not null then it will return the value of `helper.Settings.HasConfig` otherwise will return false.

N.B: if `helper?.Settings` is null then NULL reference exception will occur.

Answer (score 6):

`?.` Operator is known as the `safe navigation operator` introduced in C# 6. 
Null Conditional Operator Syntax

The null conditional operator (?.) is colloquially referred to as the `"Elvis operator"` because of its resemblance to a pair of dark eyes under a large quiff of hair. The null conditional is a form of a member access operator (the .). Here's a simplified explanation for the null conditional operator:

The expression `A?.B` evaluates to `B` if the left operand (A) is non-null; otherwise, it evaluates tonull.

> Many more details fully define the behavior:

- The type of the expression A?.B is the type of B, in cases where B is
  a reference type. If B is a value type, the expression A?.B is the
  nullable type that wraps the underlying value type represented by B.
- The specification for the feature mandates that A be evaluated no
  more than once.
- The null conditional operator short-circuits, which means that you
  can chain multiple ?.operators, knowing that the first null
  encountered prevents the remaining (rightmost) components of the
  expression from being evaluated.

*Example:- Suppose we have a Student class*

```
public class Student
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Assume that s represents a student. Consider these two statements:

```
var name = s?.FirstName;
var age = s?.Age;
```

The variable name is a string. The value of name depends on the value of `s`. If `s` is null, name is null. If `s` is not null, name is the value of `s.FirstName`. Note that `s.FirstName` may be null even when `s` is not.

The variable age is an `int?` (which is another way of specifying a Nullable). As with name, the value of age depends on the value of `s`. If s is `null`, age is an `int?` with no value. If s is non-null, age is the wrapped value of `s.Age`.

That's the basics. The power of this feature comes from all the scenarios where this feature enables cleaner code.

Answer (score 2):

It will check if "helper" is not NULL before acessing "Settings" property to avoid NullReferenceException. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx
"Old" way was like this: if (helper != null && !helper.Settings......).